# Can I Modified AES for enhaced security of WPA-2?

Tags: aes, wpa2-psk

I have topic for my research paper is modified AES algorithm for enhaced security of WPA-2 , it posible ? what i should learn ?

thanks

Comment: You might want to look at the differences between WPA-2 and WPA-3.

Comment: wpa3 maybe not available for old routers.

Comment: I also rather doubt that old routers could be modified to use a modified AES.  In any case, a) the security of AES is far from the most vulnerable piece of WPA-2, and b) if you aren't an expert in cryptography already, this sort of question "how could I modify AES" is *really* beyond your depth...

Comment: As a rule of thumb: If you use state-of-the-art crypto (like AES), then that is not gonna be the problem. It is far more likely to be used wrong, the protocol is insecure or some implementation has bugs.

Comment: AES isnt the problem with wifi security, that is why @EugeneStyer suggested looking at what they changed

Comment: thanks everyone, i get it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

AES isn't a weak point of WPA2. Modifying it would almost certainly weaken it, outside trivial stuff like adding more rounds or other things consistent with the Rijndael cipher it standardizes. And even these mods can introduce insecurity if things like hardware acceleration can no longer be used and it ceases to be constant time.

More simply both AES and WPA2 are fixed, published standards. AES is used in WPA2, modified AES isn't. Once you modify AES it's no longer AES. Once you modify WPA2 it's no longer WPA2.

Comment: thank you SAI , i have good answer now